# Which directories of a Raspbian installation can be deleted safely

Tags: sd-card

Which directories of a Raspbian installation can be deleted so that disk space is freed, but Raspbian is still able to boot onto desktop.

Backstory: I recorded with Audacity and forgot to turn recording off. So Audacity filled the whole SD card with silence and crashed. The Raspberry Pi does not boot onto desktop anymore, but I can access via SSH. So I hope to recover the session, but I need the Raspi to safely boot onto desktop again, therefore trying to recover a little space on the card.

Comment: How about inserting an USB stick 32 or 64 GB and copy the recording to it? Or copy it to another computer via network?

Comment: Sounds like that should be reported as a bug to Debian. As there should be a mechanism to prevent this from ever happening, preventing boot because no free space.

Comment: @ppumkin It hasn't actually prevented boot; note he can still SSH in.  It wouldn't be a bug, since it is expected behaviour.  The filesystem should have 5% reserved for superuser purposes, which is why it can still boot and `sshd` still works; this means root can still log in and fix the problem.  It won't make any difference to say, "We'll reserve this much of the filesystem for Bob so Bob can use it after Bob has used everything else Bob could use" -- once Bob's used all the space Bob could use first Bob will just use the space Bob can now use second.

Comment: Ahh right. Yes. It just X cannot start because it cant create swap? OK, that is how I understood that and thought it was  bug because I misread the question :) Thanks

Comment: It's not about about swap, swap is for overflow from RAM.  It's because the GUI desktop makes use of various little files on disk.  E.g., the basic X server writes a `~/.Xauthority` file as your user.  It's only a handful of bytes but more than zero (and the fs uses 4K blocks anyway).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

System directories don't exist for no reason, so don't start deleting them willy-nilly.

If you did this as user pi, chances are the data is in `/home/pi` somewhere, but sometimes applications will also use `/tmp` as it is world writable, or somewhere in `/var` if they have a writable location there.<sup>1</sup>  Commonly `/tmp` is actually a small, in memory directory (meaning it won't hold much and does not persist across boots) but I believe this is not the case by default on current versions of Raspbian (there are a few similar things though; you can check for such directories with `mount | grep "^tmpfs"` -- but these are obviously not the problem here).

A good tool for finding this kind of thing is `du`; this will give you per directory totals for a tree, e.g.:

```
> du -h /home/pi/temp
11.4M   /home/pi/temp/bearPics/candid_poses
19M     /home/pi/temp/bearPics
172K    /home/pi/temp/foobarTutorial
9.0M    /home/pi/temp/sunshine
28M     /home/pi/temp/
```

The `-h` provides more "human" digestible numbers (with units).  Here you can see `/home/pi/temp` contains a total of 28 MB, most of it in `bearPics`, most of that in `bearPics/candid_poses`.

With large trees, it may be easier to use `du -h -d 1`, where the `-d 1` means to show just 1 level deep; you can then analyze individual subdirectories from there.  If you want to get really fancy (thanks stevieb from comments below):

```
 du -h /home/pi | sort -n -r | head -n 10
```

Will show you the top 10 largest directories in descending order; logically the top one will be `/home/pi`, since it includes everything inside.

Don't try this on `/` as it will take a long time.  You can try it on `/home/pi`, which will probably give you a long list (somewhere `-d 1` might help) but the last line is always the grand total, meaning it is easy to tell whether this is the place or not.

If not check `/var` and `/tmp`.  There is more information on `du` in `man du`.

---

<sup>1. If it is outside of `/home`, don't delete the actual directory when you find it unless it is owned by the user whose data it contains; just delete the fat data files inside. Otherwise the application may not be able to recreate the (possibly system wide) data directory when run as a normal user.</sup>

Comment: another piece you may want to add is run a `lsof | grep -i deleted`. Any large ones in there can be safely deleted, as they are simply files that were deleted by processes, but the process may still be running. I can't remember if `lsof` is installed by default, but a `sudo apt-get install lsof` will fix that

Comment: another useful trick is to list files, and sort by size: `du -h /home/pi | sort -n -r | head -n 10`. That'll show the 10 largest files, by size in descending order

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: If they show up with `lsof` as deleted, they *are* already flagged for deletion, but have not yet been removed from disk because the process that deleted them has not yet freed them. This problem is very common with things like web servers, where they delete their own large log files, but aren't freed from disk yet because the process hasn't yet been restarted since the delete.

Comment: @stevieb The OP obviously rebooted several times after the crash, so `lsof` is unlikely to be useful.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I've seen stranger things. A process that starts up with creating a large throwaway temp file then after it's bootstrapped, deletes it but does not free it. It was just a thought :)

Comment: @stevieb OK, and what command do you suggest to free already deleted files from the disk?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev restart the process with `kill -HUP ...` or kill it outright until the problem is resolved or the like. I should have mentioned that

Comment: @stevieb Since the OP says "Raspberry Pi does not boot onto desktop anymore", I guess there are no survivors already.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev again, it was just a thought. Easiest way would probably be sort the common culprit directories (temp, log, home) by file size, and delete and/or scp a few of the larger ones over the network, remove them temporarily, get the UI back up, do the work, remove the audio files, restore the backed up files from the network\

Comment: @stevieb Thx for the `sort | head` trick, I've edited that in.  Sounds almost psychological ;)

Comment: @goldilocks Thank you for your insights. I used your suggestions to delete `/home/pi/.config/epiphany` and `/home/pi/.cache/webkitgtk/disk-image-cache`. The Raspi booted onto desktop again afterwards.

Comment: Also useful for a few mb of disk space: apt-get clean

Answer (score 3):

According to [documentation](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/directories_preferences.html), Audacity saves its files in `/var/tmp/audacity-<your username>`. That should be the first candidate for cleanup.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe the OP wants to keep those files to attempt to restore/recover the Audacity session after access to the UI is possible.

Comment: @stevieb >_< Yeah missed that the first time.  However in that case, if the card has been filled up with application data, it is crazy to start deleting system stuff "temporarily" to get the system to do a GUI boot; either other user stuff should be deleted, or, since the OP can still use SSH, transfer the Audacity stuff off that way.  Trying to make it useful on the pi itself is a bit of a lost cause.

Comment: I'm not sure, didn't he say Audacity recoded silence? In any case, read "cleanup" as "copy those files somewhere if needed, and remove them from SD card"

Answer (score 1):

While strictly not directories as asked in the question, I will answer with the understanding that recovering some free disk space is the intent. Depending on how many packages' debs have been cached, you could gain nothing, something or a lot of disk space using `apt-get autoclean`. [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2243852) thread has some relevant discussion on the topic. Be sure read and understand what the various options `apt-get` supports before executing the commands.